# Cómo guardar más de 1 opción en un checkbox? (Laravel)

Tags: laravel-5, checkbox

buen día, disculpen, tengo el problema, de que cuando elijo más de 1 opción siempre se guarda el ultimo seleccionado :/, podrían ayudarme?, anexo el código que manejo:

view.blade.php

```
@elseif($question->question_type === 'checkbox')
          @foreach($question->option_name as $key=>$value)
          <p style="margin:0px; padding:0px;"> <input id="{{ $value }}" name="{{ $question->id }}[answer]" type="checkbox" value="{{ $value }}" />
            <label for="{{ $value }}">{{ $value }}</label>
          </p>
          @endforeach
        @endif
```

AnswerController.php

```
public function store(Request $request, Survey $survey) 
{

//MODIFICAR PARA GUARDAR MULTIPLES CHECKBOX
// remove the token
  $arr = $request->except('_token');
  foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    $newAnswer = new Answer();
    if (is_array( $value )) {  
      $newValue = $value['answer']; 
    } else {
      $newValue = $value['answer'];
    }

    $newAnswer->answer = $newValue;
    $newAnswer->question_id = $key;
    $newAnswer->user_id = Auth::id();
    $newAnswer->survey_id = $survey->id;

    $newAnswer->save();

  };
  return redirect()->action('SurveyController@view_survey_answers', [$survey->id]);
}
```

De antemano muchas gracia :3

Answer (score 0):

si quiere enviar varios datos con un checkbox lo primero que tiene que hacer es defini en name="nombre_de_campo[]" eso lo define como un array

```
 <input id="{{ $value }}" name="nombre_de_campo[]"
 type="checkbox" value="{{ $question->id}}" />
```

y en el controlador como es un array lo tiene que corre con un foreach

aqui le dejor un ejemplo, si utilizar varios checkbox, en mi opinon es una relación de uno a mucho

```
 $permissions = $request['nombre_de_campo'];
      foreach ($permissions as $permission) {
                $p = Permission::where('id', '=', $permission)->firstOrFail(); //Get corresponding form permission in db

                $newAnswer->answer = $permission;
                $newAnswer->question_id = $key;
                $newAnswer->user_id = Auth::id();
                $newAnswer->survey_id = $survey->id;

                $newAnswer->save();

            }
```